# Returning values from custom view

Tags: android, custom-view, android-custom-view

I have made a class `ShowWeight` extending `LinearLayout`, which has two custom Views as Inner classes. I am using this class by means of an XML tag in the main.xml :

```
<org.test.ShowWeight  android:id="@+id/sw"..................../>
```

There are two public variables in the ShowWeight class, whose changing values need to be captured in the main activity, which uses `main.xml` as its view.

How do I do this?
I tried this in the main activity :

```
ShowWeight sw=(ShowWeight)this.findViewById(R.id.sw);
Log.d("test",sw.getContentDescription().toString());
```

and this in the showWeight class:

```
this.setContentDescription(/*required value */);
```

This resulted in a `NullPointerException`.

Would appreciate some suggestions (Database, static variables, not an option)

#### Update:

Unfortunately, I am not permitted to post any of the code, I apologize if I seem vague, nevertheless I'm sure the `ShowWeight` class hasn't altered anything that might be causing the problem.

The ShowWeight class, which I have added to the main.xml view by means of an XML tag appears fine and functions properly.

When I use `ShowWeight sw=(ShowWeight)this.findViewById(R.id.sw);` in the Main Activity and then Toast or print ShowWeight I am getting 'null' . Also the `setContentDescription(),getContentDescription()` shouldn't throw errors because I've given a default contentDescription in the XML tag for ShowWeight.

Comment: Post your ShowWeight class sample code.. if I 'm correctly assuming your showweight object is getting instantiated properly so probably your setContentDescription method is throwing the exception. .. but I would like to know from where are you calling this.setContentDescription method ???

Answer (score 0):

Posting your ShowWeight class will help us more.
Assuming that you have class like this.

```
public class ShowWeight extends LinearLayout {

    private Object myObject; 
    public ShowWeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, this);
    }
    public Object getMyObject()
    {
        return myObject;
    }    
}
```

and in you MainActivity.java

```
ShowWeight sw=(ShowWeight)this.findViewById(R.id.sw);
sw.getMyObject();
```